# How would I groupby and extract the N highest for a different column of that group in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi how's it going? Here's a sample dataframe..

```
  val team_df = Seq(("yankees","aaron judge",24),("yankees","giancarlo stanton",20),("yankees","brett gardner",11),("dodgers","cody bellinger",20),("dodgers","jock pederson",10),
    ("dodgers","justin turner",15)).toDF("team","player","hits")
```

and here's a screenshot in tabular format:

[image]

say I wanted to return a dataframe for each team, with the rows of the 2 highest players per team in hits (or N highest).

So it should return one dataframe for yankees with aaron judge 24 and gianarlo stanton 20, and one dataframe for the dodgers with cody bellinger 20 and justin turner 15, in this toy example.

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: It seems you already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64102959/how-to-select-the-n-highest-values-for-each-category-in-spark-scala) which was answered with a nice solution not long ago.  Didn't the suggested Window `rank` method solve your problem?

Comment: Your question is already answered if you want N highest from a team. However, kindly clarify as per your second part of the question, why do you want the results in a separate dataframe and not in a single dataframe? so as to understand and provide a solution for the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def findMultipleDF(df: DataFrame, NHighest:Int): Map[String, DataFrame] = {
  val map = Map[String, DataFrame]()
  val rankedDF = df.withColumn("Rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("team").orderBy($"hits".desc)))
  val count = df.groupBy("team").count().collect()
  count.map(x => {
    val tempDF = rankedDF.filter($"team" === x.get(0) && col("Rank").leq(NHighest)).toDF()
    map.+=((x.get(0).toString(), tempDF))
  })
  map
}

val output = findMultipleDF(team_df, 2)
output.map(x=>{
  x._2.show()
})
+-------+--------------+----+----+
|   team|        player|hits|Rank|
+-------+--------------+----+----+
|dodgers|cody bellinger|  20|   1|
|dodgers| justin turner|  15|   2|
+-------+--------------+----+----+
+-------+-----------------+----+----+
|   team|           player|hits|Rank|
+-------+-----------------+----+----+
|yankees|      aaron judge|  24|   1|
|yankees|giancarlo stanton|  20|   2|
+-------+-----------------+----+----+
```

You can try like above but not sure why you want to have output in different dataframe.